# Can motion be characterized without time as independent variable?

Tags: kinematics, time, speed, distance

I was just thinking about speed = distance/time which relatively describes how fast something is moving wrt some still object.
So if by some wishful thinking or some coordinate system I remove the time component i.e. t=0 the speed will be infinity which is absurd at first sight but how will we perceive and comprehend the motion without time as independent variable?

How do one imagine only spatial motion without time and event-like approach?
What will it look like and how does one describe it physically and mathematically?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. You can't "remove the time component".

Comment: Yeah I understand, but why not? Even as a so called "thought experiment"? One can argue that you can remove a spatial dimension for 1D, 2D or 3D motion, so why not time?

Comment: Because the word motion means "change of position with time". No time, no motion.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace time, t, with another parameter; the most useful is the arclength, s. Just as t=0 is when the trip started, so is s=0.

Arclength is a geometric parameter, and is defined by the actual motion. It is often used in relativity, bot Special and General, because it allows you to treat both space and time as coordinates, and removes time from its privileged position as parameter.

In this case both time and space are parameterized by the arclength.  This is the usual approach with differential geometry.  Draw some curves and think about  d/ds of the parametized curve, and the meaning of ds/dt.

Comment: Using arclength causes a loss of physical information, though. If you have two bodies in motion and you parametrize each with their own arclength, then you lose any ability to tell the relative position of the two bodies. Time, whether we like it, or not, does have a very special position on the world.

Comment: Note that proper time is a form of arclength along a worldline.

Comment: Yes, but it's not an arclength in the actual space in which motion happens but in an imaginary space that doesn't exist. The geometry of the world is three dimensional, only the description of the world becomes four dimensional by leaving out very important characteristics of time which do not matter for the purpose.

Comment: I agree with Peter, have a +1 from me. CuriousOne and I have differed before about the interpretation of time :-)